# What would it take to get auto-revert-mode to actually work in my dired buffer?

Tags: emacs, revert

Apparently auto-revert-mode is supposed to work in dired buffers.
I had never heard of this, but [the doc says it works](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html).

Then I read a little more and found some fine print:

> Auto-reverting Dired buffers currently works on GNU or Unix style operating systems. ***It may not work satisfactorily on some other systems***.

...and...

> [dired buffers] do not auto-revert when information about a particular file changes (e.g. when the size changes) or when inserted subdirectories change. To be sure that all listed information is up to date, you have to manually revert using g, even if auto-reverting is enabled in the Dired buffer.

[source](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Reverting-Dired.html#Auto-Reverting-Dired)

Well, uh, gee.... That doesn't sound like autorevert to me.
What would it take to get auto-revert for dired to actually work?  Even on (gasp) non-Unix operating systems.

Could I just modify `auto-revert-handler` to call `revert-buffer` on dired buffers?

Comment: auto-revert could be implemented using `inotify` on Linux http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=inotify There might not be any efficient way to do it on the "non-Unix" OS.

Answer (score 1):

[This class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) may be of-use for later Windows OS's, but t.b.h. I've no idea how to integrate into emacs \ auto-revert. Believe you've done similar work before Cheeso (c# \ powershell integration), so I'd imagine you're the expert.

Comment: yeah, I've done some work on emacs listp modules.  I'm trying to decide if it's worth building an auto-revert for dired on Windows.